# mean.js: commom variable across controllers and models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs, mvw

In mean.js I need to declare a common variable to be used across client controllers and server models (a same module)

```
  var _origens_list = [
      { id: 1, tipo: "Manual1",    nome: "Manual" },
      { id: 2, tipo: "Automática", nome: "Metodo 1" },
      { id: 3, tipo: "Automática", nome: "Metodo 2" },
      { id: 4, tipo: "Automática", nome: "Metodo 3" }
  ];
```

Where and how a declare it to have it declared once?

kind regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the common approach for caching data in angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721684/whats-the-common-approach-for-caching-data-in-angular-js)

Comment: @PaulSweatte aren't you confusing a "same answer that may solve different matters" with  "duplicate question"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sync indexedDB local data with Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000975/how-to-sync-indexeddb-local-data-with-server)